# Different ways to say alike to something

Tags: synonyms

I am writing a game analysis and don't want to say the word "fellow". I originally had "This is where guild wars 2 differs from its fellow games ... " How else could I word this? I have included the sentence before it for context.

> Questing is the biggest staple of any MMO you will ever play; there isn’t a game out there that doesn’t require the player to either kill some bad guys or bring the quest giver ten of a certain item. This is where Guild Wars 2 differs from its <s>fellow games</s> ...

Thank you.

Comment: I'll upvote the question for including enough context.

Comment: @A.P.  But I'll close-vote for not looking up and mentioning synonyms of  'fellow' found in dictionaries and lists of synonyms. 'Same kind' and 'similar'  are soon found.

Comment: To the extent that Guild Wars 2 is competing against other MMO games for potential players' time and money, you could say "its rivals" or "the competition."

Answer (score 1):

"Differs from similar games" possibly?

Answer (score 0):

You've already mentioned the similarity by talking about other games that use questing. Why highlight it even further by using words like "similar" or "alike"? You're emphasizing the *difference* now, correct?

If you want to make your writing more impactful, consider rewriting the sentence to something like:

> This is where Guild Wars 2 is **different from the rest**: ...
>
> This is where Guild Wars 2 **[stands out from the crowd](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+out+from+the+crowd)**: ...
>
> This is where Guild Wars 2 is **strikingly different**: ...
>
> This is where Guild Wars 2 is **unlike any other MMO game on the market**: ...
>
> This is where Guild Wars 2 is **unique**: ...

Of course, things like "unique" and "strikingly different" will only work if the game is, in fact, strikingly different.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***differ from other games of its kind/genre***.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using its "[***peers***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peer)" as the noun "peer" means:

> something of ***equal worth or quality***.

The word peer isn't always used to describe a person.

[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary]

Or its "[***competitive***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competitive) games" as the adjective "competitive" means:

> ***As good as*** or better than others of a ***comparable nature***.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]